# Error CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED with nn.Linear

Tags: pytorch

```
from torch import nn
from transformers.models.bert.modeling_bert import BertConfig

config =  BertConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
self.x_head = nn.Linear(in_features=config.hidden_size, out_features=28)

word_embeddings = nn.Embedding( num_embeddings=979, embedding_dim=config.hidden_size ,padding_idx=0,)(ids_1).to(self.device)
vis_embeddings = nn.Embedding( num_embeddings=127, embedding_dim=config.hidden_size, padding_idx=0,)(ids_2).to(self.device)
        
input_embeds = torch.cat([word_embeddings , vis_embeddings] , dim =1).to(self.device)

in forward() method I have below code:

x_scores = self.x_head(input_embeds)
```

I am getting below error at x_scores(last line above)

~/pytorch-env_py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/pytorch-env_py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py in forward(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
166                 return self.module(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
167             replicas = self.replicate(self.module, self.device_ids[:len(inputs)])
--> 168             outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs)
169             return self.gather(outputs, self.output_device)
170

~/pytorch-env_py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py in parallel_apply(self, replicas, inputs, kwargs)
176
177     def parallel_apply(self, replicas, inputs, kwargs):
--> 178         return parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids[:len(replicas)])
179
180     def gather(self, outputs, output_device):

~/pytorch-env_py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py in parallel_apply(modules, inputs, kwargs_tup, devices)
84         output = results[i]
85         if isinstance(output, ExceptionWrapper):
---> 86             output.reraise()
87         outputs.append(output)
88     return outputs

~/pytorch-env_py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_utils.py in reraise(self)
423             # have message field
424             raise self.exc_type(message=msg)
--> 425         raise self.exc_type(msg)
426
427

RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in replica 0 on device 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/gems/pytorch-env_py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 61, in _worker
output = module(*input, **kwargs)
File "/home/gems/pytorch-env_py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "", line 56, in forward
x_scores = self.x_head(input_embeds)
File "/home/gems/pytorch-env_py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/home/gems/pytorch-env_py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 96, in forward
return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
File "/home/gems/pytorch-env_py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1847, in linear
return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`